# Getting rid of UIWebView in Bolts framework (Parse framework dependecy)

Tags: ios, xcode, heroku, bolts-framework, parse-framework

I recently started working with XCode on a project where we are using Parse framework to load data into MongoDB with Heroku.
So I have to release this new app (replica of an existing app with some mods) to App store but I get error email saying UIWebView needs to be replaced with WKWebView.
I searched for the other libraries using UIWebView and could replace them with other ones or a simple pod update worked.
But I am not sure about the Parse.freamework below.
Here is the project structure:
[image]

Now I think this is not the Cocoapod implementation. Since, I am fairly new to iOS development, I am not even sure how did these Parse.framework and Bolts.framework come here.

So can someone please help me understand or directly me to documentation that will direct me or help me with some search phrases at least so I can do the hard work of researching.
My questions are:

1. Why are these Frameworks here in the root folder of project? I don't think this is Pod's doing, is it? How is this implementation of framework done? What is it called?
2. How can I update the Bolts and/or Parse frameworks to get rid of UIWebView?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the frameworks and installing the newest version through Cocoa Pods?

Comment: No I didn't. I wanted to exhaust other options first if possible. This is because I am not sure how and why are these Bolts.Framework and Parse.Framework in project root and not in pods folder.

Comment: They were probably added manually. The FBSDK used to have people just drag in the Bolts.framework directly into the project.

Comment: Ok. Understood. So they drag them manually in so that they appear in the Frameworks section of XCode project navigator. And that might be why it had encrypted libraries which I could not find on Parse's github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to re-iterate, @Wyetro suggested to install pods anyways. So removed the dependencies (from Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content). Then I installed Parse and it installed Bolts since its dependency through pods. And it all worked perfectly fine!!!

Thank you Wyetro...